# Could not parse the remainder: '{{' from '{{'

Tags: python, html, django, parsing, if-statement

I'm trying to create a simple page, which should display a table.
It suppose to have several rows and columns. But not every row should have the same amount of columns.

this my html code which is producing an error:

```
<html>
  {% for count in machine_count %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ count }}</td>
            <td>Aufzugmotor</td>

            {% for status in statuses %}
                 {{ status.machine_number}}
                {% if count == {{ status.machine_number }} %}
                    <td class="tableCell">
                        <img class="imageClass" src={{ status.src }}>
                    </td>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
</html>
```

statuses is a model and machine_number is a tuple of strings.

I'm not really getting the mistake I made.
Is it not possible to use the if-tag on a placeholder ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{% if count == {{ status.machine_number }} %}
```

Should be:

```
{% if count == status.machine_number %}
```

Comment: But is it really taking the information out of the model object?

Comment: Because even if the machine_number exist it doesn't display anything. So I thought that if I am doing it that way it doesn't fetch the right data.

Answer (score 1):

`{{...}}` is only used for injecting variable contents to the final output. Omit them if you're using the variable in other situations.